# HOw to change Lookup-filter error message?

Tags: configuration

HOw to change Lookup-filter error message without customization , it should display custom message in Lookup if I enter unavailable value it should show me a message like create new contact/Account....

Answer (score 1):

While creating a lookup field , go to the section where you can add Filters for lookup there you can make field as required there you can Reset the default error message.

[image]